# how to fetch record by pagination using Fetch query and CRMSDK2015 from MS CRM to Android?

Tags: android, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

by using sdk and fetch query i got 5000 records in one request and it takes too much time for fetch.

please give me suggestion how to get records in page by page using Fetch query and sdk in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Android SDK bit but FetchXML Paging is covered here: [Page large result sets with FetchXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309717.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Linq. Have a look here -
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334684.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in `Query Expression` as well:
[Page large result sets with QueryExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327917(v=crm.6).aspx)

// Query using the paging cookie.
// Define the paging attributes.
// The number of records per page to retrieve.

```
int queryCount = 3;
```

// Initialize the page number.

```
int pageNumber = 1;
```

// Initialize the number of records.

```
int recordCount = 0;
```

// Define the condition expression for retrieving records.

```
ConditionExpression pagecondition = new ConditionExpression();
pagecondition.AttributeName = "parentaccountid";
pagecondition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
pagecondition.Values.Add(_parentAccountId);
```

// Define the order expression to retrieve the records.

```
OrderExpression order = new OrderExpression();
order.AttributeName = "name";
order.OrderType = OrderType.Ascending;
```

// Create the query expression and add condition.

```
QueryExpression pagequery = new QueryExpression();
pagequery.EntityName = "account";
pagequery.Criteria.AddCondition(pagecondition);
pagequery.Orders.Add(order);
pagequery.ColumnSet.AddColumns("name", "emailaddress1");
```

// Assign the pageinfo properties to the query expression.

```
pagequery.PageInfo = new PagingInfo();
pagequery.PageInfo.Count = queryCount;
pagequery.PageInfo.PageNumber = pageNumber;
```

// The current paging cookie. When retrieving the first page, 
// pagingCookie should be null.

```
pagequery.PageInfo.PagingCookie = null;
Console.WriteLine("Retrieving sample account records in pages...\n");
Console.WriteLine("#\tAccount Name\t\tEmail Address"); 

while (true)
{
// Retrieve the page.
EntityCollection results = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(pagequery);
if (results.Entities != null)
{
    // Retrieve all records from the result set.
    foreach (Account acct in results.Entities)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}.\t{1}\t{2}", ++recordCount, acct.Name,
                           acct.EMailAddress1);
    }
}

// Check for more records, if it returns true.
if (results.MoreRecords)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n****************\nPage number {0}\n****************", pagequery.PageInfo.PageNumber);
    Console.WriteLine("#\tAccount Name\t\tEmail Address");

    // Increment the page number to retrieve the next page.
    pagequery.PageInfo.PageNumber++;

    // Set the paging cookie to the paging cookie returned from current results.
    pagequery.PageInfo.PagingCookie = results.PagingCookie;
}
else
{
    // If no more records are in the result nodes, exit the loop.
    break;
}
}
```